# Como hago que el sistema reconozca mi app como visor de imágenes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Un saludo a toda la comunidad, he creado una aplicacion de galeria personal ya que mi telefono tenia una, me encuentro con el detalle de que no se como hacer ni como se llama esta opcion, en es file xplorer toco una imagen para abrirla y me salen algunas apps con las que se puede abrir, **como hago para que reconozca la mia como un visor de imagenes ?**

[image: Captura de Es File Xplorer]

Gracias por el apoyo, les agradecería cualquier comentario que me ayude a encontrar esta solución, así sea como puedo buscar info sobre esto.

Comment: Échale un ojo a este enlace, creo que responde a tu pregunta: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html#AddIntentFilter

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar algo llamado intents implicitos y un intent flilter. La documentacion de esto puede ser encontrada [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

En resumen hay **dos tipo de intents**. Los explicitos son aquellos que requieren de la dirección y nombre exacto del archivo que va a ser lanzado. Este tipo de intents se usan cuando hacemos una navegación entre dos activities. Pero un intent implícito, genera una acción y busca dentro del pool de posibles activites aquel que sea capaz de tomar esta acción y sea capaz de hacer algo con ello. Para ello, debemos configurar nuestro activity de tal forma que sea capaz de filtrar cierto tipo de intents. Para nuestro caso, ya que queremos usar un visor de imágenes debemos definir en nuestro manifest lo siguiente.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ImageViewerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Aqui le estamos diciendo al sistema que, este activity es capaz de recibir intents del tipo image/cualquier extencion Para poder Verla y con una categoria por defecto (te recomiendo leas la documentacion para entender cada parametro)

Para recuperar la informacion te recomiendo que mires este [DEMO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjZammCFEPc&t=0s&list=PLlyCyjh2pUe9wv-hU4my-Nen_SvXIzxGB&index=15), sacado directamente del curso oficial de android

Este video es una buen complemento a la documentación y para que aprendas como funcionan los intents implícitos

Mucha suerte.